# How to force the use of JRE7?

Tags: java

im on a windows 8 operating system, and i would like to know how to force the use of java 7? I have java 7 on my computer, but at the moment it is defaulting to java 6.

I need java 7, because BungeeCord, Made by md_5 (www.spigotmc.org), only runs with java 7 :(.

Is there some sort of path i need to force it to use?

I have currently tried putting -d64 and -jar in the .bat file, which is not helping or doing anything (and i have have 32 bit java), and my start script is at the bare minimum.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Have you tried setting up JAVA_HOME in Advanced Settings?

Comment: You need to set your path variable to point to the JRE7 directory instead of the JRE6 directory

Comment: Google for setting up environment variable in window 7. then set the path of jre7 as environment variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable and also point your path variable to the java 7 bin folder.

[Here](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Java-Home) is a visual rep of how to set up.(Note: make changes to paths according ur system and also use version numbers correctly)

Comment: yup. and be careful for sneaky java.exe in system32. for extra safety place %JAVA_HOME%\bin before system32 on the path

Comment: Thanks. How do i access the JAVA_HOME enviroment?

Comment: I have edited my answer and have included a link on how to do that.Take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Change `Environment variable` to java 7 bin folder. Here's how to do it on Windows 8: https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them